# I was rejected and told to leave Canada - can I enter again?

Tags: canada, saudi-citizens, refugees

I lived in Canada from 2007 until 2011. I applied for refuge and was rejected. I appealed, this was also rejected again and I was told to leave Canada. So I left the country.

Now it's 6 years since I left Canada, and right now I'm in the US, trying to enter Canada from the border and apply for refuge again.

My questions are:

1. Is it dangerous to come to Canada again this way?
2. Will they return me to the US?
3. I have serious problems in my country; can I come and apply for a new case with the evidence?
4. If I enter Canada, I know they will find my old case when I make fingerprints; does this prevent me from entering?
5. If they allow me, will I get financial support like I had before?

edited:

When I came to Canada originally I came on student visa. I couldn't go back to Saudi Arabia because I would be put in jail so I filed for asylum. Canada didn't accept my case. I made an appeal but it also was rejected and I was told to leave back to my country.

I went back and of course I was put in jail. I got out and lived normally without any problem for six years. Suddenly I was called by the government for a  DNA test because my father wasn't my genetic father and also my mother was not my genetic mother.

My original mom was Eritrean but she couldn't get an ID for me so my father put me as his son in the paperwork and his wife as my mom so the government of Saudi Arabia will give me a national ID. My genetic mother is not listed in my ID paperwork.

A problem happened between my father and his wife so she went to the police station and reported that i wasn't her son and wasn't also her husband's son and that my real mother is an Eritrean.

The Government of Saudi Arabia immediately stopped my national ID services. They  called for an investigation and forced me to take a DNA test. I said OK but  left the country. I know if they find out the truth they will take my ID and send me back to Eritrea. People are fleeing Eritrea because life is not safe there.

This is my story. I'm sorry that it's long but this is the truth and I have paper from the government of Saudi Arabia that I'm wanted as evidence.

Now I'm in USA legal on a tourist visa.

Will this allow me to enter?

Comment: Your question needs more info, please [edit] it. (1) What was your status in 2007-2011 before you applied for refugee status? I'm asking because you talk about *financial support* that you got. (2) What was the official reason for denying your refugee status? Quote the text or add a good picture of the document. (3) Do you think anything relevant has changed from your earlier application until now. Especially, is that *serious problem in my country* anything that came up after 2011? What is it? (4) Is your current status/presence in the US legal? What is it? (5) What is your nationality?

Comment: How can you possibly apply for refugee status in Canada when you are already in a safe country? You lived somewhere for six years, you can't possibly be in the kind of danger that makes one a refugee. What am I missing here? Also, what do you mean by dangerous? The US-Canadian border in the ordinary sense of this word is not dangerous, there is no minefield or a high current fence, even those who illegally cross are typically not shot on spot. I lived behind the Iron Curtain, I know what's a dangerous border is, this is not one.

Comment: Refugee is a type of settlement. Please consider Expats http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions for questions about moving to some place for a lengthy period of time.

Comment: @chx That's a good question, but people do it all the time. While many applications are turned away under the 'safe third country' agreement, not all are.

Comment: @chx, I don't think the person is asking about crossing at an official border crossing; people crossing elsewhere acquire some due process rights (I hear Roxham Road in Champlain NY is currently busy). As for danger, it is summer but one might still trip over a hedge or fall in a ditch. Somehow I think this is one of those questions that isn't supposed to be answered, though I could be reading too much into it.

Comment: This is a complex situation where doing the wrong thing can have dire consequences. I'd strongly encourage you to try to seek out professional legal advice rather than relying on random people on the internet.

Comment: There is also the possibility of claiming asylum in the USA. However, you should absolutely get professional legal help.

Comment: It doesn't change @chx answer, but the reason you were put into prison may matter.

Comment: Why aren't you claiming asylum in the US?  By not doing so, you seem to be displaying the behaviour of an *economic* migrant, not a refugee...

Comment: As a refugee, under international treaties, you must ask for asylum in the nearest possible country to the country of origin. And yes, there are a lot of people breaking that and a lot of countries not abiding by it either and accepting just about anyone. As you enter Canada from the US, you should apply for asylum in the US instead of Canada, or better yet a country closer to home, like a country bordering Saudi, Jordan for example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK I can answer this after the edit: lawyer, lawyer, lawyer! Forget random sites on the Internet, your case is insanely complicated, unique, special and one bad move on your end might be irreversible. You need the help of a professional, real bad.

Here is a link to the [United States of America Pro Bono Directory](http://www.refugeelegalaidinformation.org/united-states-america-pro-bono-directory) provided by the International Refugee Rights Initiative. I do not endorse this list, their makers, or anyone in there but it *might* be a useful resource. Equally, it might not be.

Just as am I writing this, the Prime Minister of Canada [tweeted](https://twitter.com/JustinTrudeau/status/900456784091066372):

> I’m in Montreal today, working with the task force on irregular migration. Here’s how we’re taking action regarding asylum seekers in QC: First, we’ve established a temporary housing facility in Cornwall, ON to help ease the burden on Quebec. Second, we’re hiring more staff at the IRCC processing centre in Montreal to review & process asylum claimants faster. Third, we’re also reaching out to folks in the US to make sure people who want to come to Canada understand the proper procedures to do so. Canada is an open and welcoming society. But just as we welcome & encourage newcomers, we are also a country of laws. Canadians can be confident in our immigration system - **people who cross the border in an irregular way will not be at an advantage**.

Emphasis mine.